# Bootstrap "slid" event firing too early

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I wrote a function which extends Bootstrap's carousel to automatically shrink or extend the height of a slide while it is sliding. I wanted to be able to have slides of different heights with a smooth transition. My solution is working occasionally, but sometimes the slide that is fading will go blank well before the slide is done, causing it to appear like a very awkward clipping. I am not sure exactly what is causing this but it seems to be related to the "slid" event firing sooner than it should be. With a breakpoint over the slid event-handler function, I can catch the event happening well before the slider has finished. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

```
$.fn.carouselAutoHeight = function (options) {

    var maxHeight = options.height;

    $(this).carousel({
        wrap: false
    }).carousel("pause");

    $(this).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e){
        var $newDiv = $(e.relatedTarget)
        var $previousDiv = $(".item.slider.active", this);
        $newDiv.css({
            position:   'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden',
            display:    'block'
        });
        var targetHeight = $newDiv.height();

        $newDiv.attr("style", "")
        function finishAnimate(){
            $newDiv.css("position", "relative");
            $(this).css("height", "");
        }
        $previousDiv.stop().animate({
            height: targetHeight + "px"
        }, "slow", finishAnimate);
        $(this).unbind('slid.bs.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e){
            var x = 0;
            $(e.target).find(".item:not(.active)").attr("style","");
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Any chance of a bootply.com or jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was bothering me for months and I finally got it. turns out the 'slid' event is fired when the active item has finished its transition, which looks like this

```
$active.one($.support.transition.end, function (e) {
    $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
    $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
    that.sliding = false
    setTimeout(function () { that.$element.trigger('slid.bs.carousel') }, 0)
}).emulateTransitionEnd($active.css('transition-duration').slice(0, -1) * 1000)
```

which means that if any other transitions occur and ends within your sliding item, it will cause the slide to terminate early. now, to my knowledge I had no such transition going on (I never wrote one).

HOWEVER, it turns out that an input field of type text DOES have a native transition going on in chrome (possibly other browsers) that causes it to glow blue when focused. as soon as my slide event began, the input was blurred, causing the transition to fade from blue. once that transition finished, it triggered my carousel to immediately finish sliding prematurely

it should be noted that bootstrap was not designed to have such interactive content inside of carousels, I am simply breaking the rules. but it is definitely important to note that such native transitions may be occurring "invisibly" in your document.